# Should I install VirtualBox Guest Additions in an Ubuntu USB install?

Tags: boot, usb, virtualbox

I've installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 32bits in a 16GB USB pen drive (ext2 formatted). Note this is a real installation, not a liveUSB.

It works fine both from a real machine's BIOS and from another machine's VirtualBox under Windows (doing [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/)).

Now, if I install VirtualBox Guest Additions, will it continue booting from the real machine's BIOS, or will it give errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel modules provided with the guest additions should only load when booting Ubuntu in a version matching VirtualBox environment but not on bare metal. It should therefore be safe to install the guest addition which provide better graphics, USB support, and shared folders functionality.

However booting a VM from raw disk rather than from a virtual drive is not how VirtualBox is designed to perform best. It is therefore possible that the kernel modules don't play nice on a bare metal boot. You will have to test this for your individual setting.

Just install the guest additions while in a virtual environment. In case you are not happy on bare metal you can always boot to a VM in order to remove the guest additions with:

```
cd /opt/<VirtualBoxAdditions-x.x.xx>/
sudo ./uninstall.sh
```